# how to get the file path to my csv file in data assets in watson studio?

Tags: python, filereader, ibm-watson

I have been trying to get the file path of my csv file in watson studio. The file is saved in my project data assets in watson studio. And all I need is the file path to read its content in a jupyter notebook. I'm trying to use a simple python file reader, that should read a file in a specified path. I have tried using watson studio insert file credentials, but can't get it to work.
This works fine when I run the same file in IBM cognitiveclass.ai platform, but I can't get this to work in IBM watson studio, please help.

file name is enrollments.csv

```
import unicodecsv
with open('enrollments.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
    enrollments = list(reader)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean uploaded the "enrollments.csv" file to Files section.
This uploads file to the Bucket of Cloud Object Storage service which storage for your project.
You can use project-lib to fetch the file url.

```
# Import the lib
from project_lib import Project
project = Project(sc,"<ProjectId>", "<ProjectToken>")

# Get the url
url = project.get_file_url("myFile.csv")
```

For more refer this:-
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/a972effc-394f-4825-af91-874cb165dcfc/view?access_token=ee2bd90bee679afc278cdb23453946a3922c454a6a7037e4bd3c4b0f90eb0924

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and read all the links but it did not work. I generated the project ID and token successfully, but the code to get url (url = project.get_file_url('enrollments.csv') gives an error message, that says "ValueError: Something went wrong! error message:ProjectCore__get_file_url(): spark context (sc) is not available. This function can't be invoked!!" I have no idea why, it's more than a bit frustrating I must say. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future readers, try this one.

1. Upload your csv file as your asset in your Watson Studio Project (you can also do this step later).
2. Open your notebook. On the top ribbon, on the upper-right corner of the page (below your name), click on the `1010` icon.
3. Make sure you're on Files tab, and below you will see the list of your uploaded datasets (you can also upload your files here).
4. Click the drop-down and choose `pandas DataFrame` to add a block of code that will load the uploaded data into your notebook. Note that you need to select a blank cell so that it doesn't mess up your existing cell that has some codes.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to define the path in Watson as well.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Within a Project, select the "Settings" tab. I believe the default view is on the "Assets" tab.
2. Create a token. Scroll down to "Access Tokens". Then click on "New token"
3. Go back to "Assets" and open your notebook.
4. Click on the three vertical dots in the header. One option is to "Insert project token". This creates a new code block that defines the correct parameters under the Project method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really asking how can you read a file from assets in your Watson Studio Project.  This is documented here :  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.0?topic=lib-watson-studio-python

```
# Import the lib
from ibm_watson_studio_lib import access_project_or_space
wslib = access_project_or_space()

# Fetch the data from a file
my_file = wslib.load_data("my_asset_name.csv")

# Read the CSV data file into a pandas DataFrame
my_file.seek(0)
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(my_file, nrows=10)
```

[Project File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubRSp.png)

[Project File Read in Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDMYo.png)

The old project-lib has been deprecated. See Deprecation Announcement https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.0?topic=notebook-using-project-lib-python-deprecated