# Upload asset(csv file) to watson studio project using python

Tags: python, python-requests, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I need to upload a csv file from my local to an existing project in Watson Studio using python.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can upload to the COS bucket of your Cloud project, using the ibm-cos-sdk package, which implements an API similar to boto3.

Comment: refer to this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224648/how-to-get-the-file-path-to-my-csv-file-in-data-assets-in-watson-studio/53235715#53235715

Comment: Achieved using COS bucket. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @charlesgomes, I can not use projectlib as I want to access my projects externally without using Watson Notebook.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Resource List > Click on Services > Db2 > Open Console > Click on Hand Burger Icon on right > Click on Load > Open Load Data > Upload your CSV File > using Drag n drop or browser

Comment: I wanted to achieve it programatically

Comment: Maybe he meant using a Python Snake to move the mouse LOL